# Loaded query tables either shows error in refresh or leave many blank rows between tables

Tags: powerquery

Dears,

I really need your help with this one as it's driving me crazy, I have 3 queries loaded as tables under each other in my excel workbook.

[image]

when I choose the properties option: **insert cells for new data, delete unused cells** from properties >> it shows an error message in refresh **(it would move cells in a table on your worksheet).**

and when I go for the second option: **insert entire rows for new data**, it refreshes **but leaves many blank rows between each table and the second one.**

What shall I do to refresh all queries in the workbook without messing up the form .. as I just need to leave 1 empty row between each loaded table?

Comment: to clarify - are you wanting to insert new rows directly into your Excel Worksheets, into tables that are connected to your data model? Or are you seeking to insert rows into Excel worksheets that are loaded from your data model?

Comment: I am seeking to insert rows into Excel worksheets that are loaded from your data model

Comment: Okay, got it. And, is it essential for you to keep all three of your loaded tables on one excel worksheet - with one blank/non-table row separating each or are you open to quick alternatives like loading your tables to different worksheets?

Comment: Also, are your tables going to grow over time in length, i.e., more rows will be added over time?

Comment: Yes sir, it varies widely over time, sadly the tables have to be over each other and seperated by spcae

Comment: Okay, forgive me for being exhaustive - but why do the tables have to be on the same worksheet? I'm only asking because the only potential solution I can think of at the moment is a VBA script - and if it would work it would take some time (at least for me) - so I just want to know why they need to be on the same worksheet first - there may be a much easier solution

Comment: i really appreciate your time replying to my issue, so thank you. for the question why.. because all these tables are colereted to each other and I've added a filter by parameter on the top of the excel sheet so people can see data from 4 tables against each other, so it's very important that all tables have to be on the same sheet.

Comment: Of course - so your challenge really isn't getting multiple loaded tables on one Excel Sheet - it's showing comparisons / calculations to others using data from multiple, distinct tables. I don't have a solution for loading/refreshing changing data into one worksheet - but would be happy to explain how to use Power Query in Excel to create a Data Model (link your tables) and create a calculated table that would give you the ability to show others comparisons/calculations between the tables - without needing to put them on one sheet. Let me know what you think - and I'll proceed.